# Find mean and sd of rows until next NA value for groups in R

Tags: r, aggregate, average

I have a dataframe with a variable RATE that has a NA value every few rows:

```
 ID    RATE
 1     10
 1     15
 1     8
 1     6
 1     NA
 1     10
 1     20
 1     NA
 1     14
 1     2
 2     8
 2     6
 2     NA
```

On these rows, I would like to add a variable mean_RATE and sd_RATE, corresponding with the average and sd of all rows between the NA rows. This average and sd is calculated only over all RATES with the same ID:

```
 ID    RATE  mean_RATE  sd_RATE
 1     10
 1     15
 1     8
 1     6
 1     NA    9.75       3.86221
 1     10
 1     20
 1     NA    15         7.071068
 1     14
 1     2
 2     8
 2     6
 2     NA    7          1.414214
```

As you can see in the desired output above, the rows corresponding with a RATE of 14 and 2 are not taken into account in any mean or sd calculation, since the next NA row has a different ID.

Can someone help me with an efficient way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID, grp = cumsum(lag(is.na(RATE), default = FALSE))) %>% 
   mutate(mean_RATE = mean(RATE, na.rm = TRUE), sd_RATE = sd(RATE, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches("_RATE")), funs(replace(., !is.na(RATE), NA)))
# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups: ID, grp [4]
#      ID  RATE   grp mean_RATE sd_RATE
#   <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1    10     0     NA      NA   
# 2     1    15     0     NA      NA   
# 3     1     8     0     NA      NA   
# 4     1     6     0     NA      NA   
# 5     1    NA     0      9.75    3.86
# 6     1    10     1     NA      NA   
# 7     1    20     1     NA      NA   
# 8     1    NA     1     15.0     7.07
# 9     1    14     2     NA      NA   
#10     1     2     2     NA      NA   
#11     2     8     2     NA      NA   
#12     2     6     2     NA      NA   
#13     2    NA     2      7.00    1.41
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try using the function `ave`.

```
mutate(dat,new=ave(RATE,a<-cumsum(c(F,head(is.na(RATE),-1))),ID,
               FUN = function(x)mean(x,na.rm=T)),
   new=`is.na<-`(new,!is.na(RATE)),
   sd=ave(RATE,a,ID,FUN=function(x)sd(x,na.rm=T)),
   sd=`is.na<-`(sd,!is.na(RATE)))


    ID RATE   new       sd
1   1   10    NA       NA
2   1   15    NA       NA
3   1    8    NA       NA
4   1    6    NA       NA
5   1   NA  9.75 5.629958
6   1   10    NA       NA
7   1   20    NA       NA
8   1   NA 15.00 5.629958
9   1   14    NA       NA
10  1    2    NA       NA
11  2    8    NA       NA
12  2    6    NA       NA
13  2   NA  7.00 1.414214
```